# how to update quotation state while send email odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

By default, state is updated as 'sent' after quotation sent through email. I would like to use email function to send notification email and update states other than 'sent' like 'approval required', 'verified' etc.

By default
Quotation (draft) -> Send Email -> Quotation (Sent)

I want notification email to be sent; rather the entire quotation using existing email function 
Quotation (draft) -> Send Email -> Quotation (Approval Required) -> Quotation (Approved) -> Quotation (Sent)

Can anyone suggest how can I do this.

Comment: You can edit the field `state` of object `sale.order` to add new states. Than you can edit the send method to set state to `approval_required`.

Comment: This is what I tried to do. My question is, once I send the email, it automatically updates the status to sent. I want to use default email function but don't want the status to be changed to 'sent' rather new state.

Comment: Okay, i have added my answer below. But you should use Odoo 11 for new development

Answer (score 0):

First you can see the file [sale.py # Line 652](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L652). When u send a e-mail, it call the wizard `mail.compose.message` with a context `'mark_so_as_sent': True`.

The next, you can look for `mail.compose.message` in the samme file, you will see it [sale.py # Line 1277](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L1277). So it call the workflow `quotation_sent` if you send e-mail.

On the file [sale_workflow.xml](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale_workflow.xml), you will see some thing like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="act_sent" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_sale"/>
            <field name="name">sent</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">write({'state':'sent'})</field>
        </record>

        <record id="trans_draft_sent" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_draft"/>
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_sent"/>
            <field name="signal">quotation_sent</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

---

Now you see, you only need to add new state into the state field and edit the workflow:

**Python**

```xml
state = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('not_approval', 'Quotation (Approval Required)')])
```

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="act_not_approval" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_approval"/>
            <field name="name">not_approval</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">write({'state':'not_approval'})</field>
        </record>

        <record id="trans_draft_sent" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_draft"/>
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_not_approval"/>
            <field name="signal">quotation_sent</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: It seems like the correct answer. But I solved by creating new custom object to update status.